# In Spree admin how could I pull in all orders completed for a state?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I'm trying to create a custom report and I want to pull in all completed orders for a specific state.

Something like:

orders = Spree::Order.complete.for_state("Utah")

How would I do this?

The part that confuses me is the fact that the state is a 3 part assocoation.

Order has_one ship_address, which is an Address instance, which then belongs_to State.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Spree::Order.complete.joins(:bill_address).where("state_name = 'Utah'")
Spree::Order.complete.joins(:ship_address).where("state_name = 'Utah'")
```

Depending on which one you are looking for.

Comment: Of course it didn't work. You were searching for 'city', not 'state_name'. :)